# Page displaying a specific category has pagination problem

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, categories

I have a client that has a Static WordPress website with a blog.

The main blog page (home.php) works great with pagination all correct.

**Note**: I am using the WP-PageNavi to do the pagination for me.

I have also created a customized template page that displays the posts from a specific category (recipes).  The pagination code doesn't work correctly on this page.  There should be two pages available, and it only shows that there is one.

I know the issue is that I need to tweak the coding for the pagination on  the recipe page, but I don't really know what to do.

This is the recipe (category) blog page link: [www.aphrodisiacsexpert.com/aphrodisiacs-expert-blog/aphrodisiac-recipes/](https://www.aphrodisiacsexpert.com/aphrodisiacs-expert-blog/aphrodisiac-recipes/)

Here is the code that displays the page with the recipes blog posts along with its pagination:

```
            <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var( 'paged' )) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'order'=> 'DESC', 
                'orderby' => 'post_date', 
                'category_name' => 'Recipes',
                'posts_per_page' => 9,
                'paged' => $paged,
            );
            $postslist = get_posts( $args );
            foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 home-blog-list" style="float: left; display:block">                
                    <center>
                      <div class="img-responsive box-shadow shadow-effect" style="">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                      </div>
                      <h3 class="entry-title script" style="text-align: center;">
                        <a class="entry-title-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                      </h3>
                    <center>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

Can anyone give me some ideas on how to fix this problem?

Thanks,
SunnyOz

Comment: I am assuming that the down vote was due to the Title not describing the question properly.  I have changed it, and also edited the description to be more concise and to the point.  (or maybe because this has already been asked an answered somewhere?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of researching, I finally found one question similar to mine (from 10 years ago) with a great solution.  It can be found here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/pagination-not-working-with-custom-loop.

The answer that helped me was provided by @ChowKaiDeng (combo of comment from @Jan Fabry and original code by @nurain)

I thought I would post the answer here to show that the solution still works in 2020 with a current version of Wordpress and the WP-PageNavi plugin.  (The problem appears to be with the PageNavi and the $wp_query variable.)

Here is my code updated with the working solution:

```
        <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $myquery = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'posts_per_page' => '9',
                'paged'=>$paged,
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'order'=> 'DESC', 
                'orderby' => 'post_date', 
                'category_name' => 'Recipes',
            )   
        );  
        ?>

        <?php
        if ($myquery->have_posts()) :  while ($myquery->have_posts()) : $myquery->the_post();
        ?>

        <!-- Start your post -->

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 home-blog-list" style="float: left; display:block">                
                <center>
                  <div class="img-responsive box-shadow shadow-effect" style="">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                  </div>
                  <h3 class="entry-title script" style="text-align: center;">
                    <a class="entry-title-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
                    </a>
                  </h3>
                <center>
            </div>

        <!-- End of your post -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $myquery ) ); ?><!-- IMPORTANT: make sure to include an array with your previously declared query values in here -->
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
        <p>No posts found</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
```